# Background of dompdf pdf is being cut

Tags: css, dompdf

The first page of my pdf is a cover page, and has a different background than the other pages. 2nd page as following. When I do this, however, the bottom of the page is missing, even if I resize the image. Oddly, I've found that using the `img` tag works fine.

```
@page { 
    size: 21cm 29.7cm; 
    margin:0;     
} 
#poppen1{ 
    background: url(mainimages/ersteseite.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    page-break-after: always;
    color:red;     
}
#poppen2{ 
    color:black;
    background: url(mainimages/zweiteseite.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding:2cm;       
    margins:0;
}
div.footer { position: fixed; bottom: 6mm;left:0.9cm; 
width:19.2cm;height:6mm;border-top:1px solid black; }` 

require_once("./dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
$html="<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title>";
include("./maincss/xyzcss.php");
$html=$html.$css_print.'</head><body>

<div id="poppen1">
text';
$html.='</div><div style="page-break-before: always;"></div><div 
id="enter code herepoppen2">
more text</div>';
$html.='</body></html>';
$dompdf=new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
@$dompdf->stream($docname);
```

Answer (score 0):

New try:

```
@page {
    size: A4;
    margin-top:2cm;
    margin-bottom:2cm;
    margin-left:2cm;
    margin-right:2cm;
    padding: 0;
  }
  body {
    font-family: helvetica !important;
    font-size: 10pt;
  }
  #overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: -2cm;
    left: -2cm;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("mainimages/ersteseite.png");
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  
}
```

Background is being cut at bottom and top left, even tried height 90% and height 21cm, and div and p . No solution....